# What permission should my files/folders in Laravel framework have for git deploy?

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, git, deployment

I have CentOS 7 VPS server, where I want have my own website. I have for example website in `/var/www/shop`. This website use Laravel framework , the apache configuration for this is

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName shop.itzena.cz

    DocumentRoot /var/www/shop/public
    <Directory /var/www/shop/public>
        AllowOverride All

        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    Errorlog /var/log/httpd/shop-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/shop-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

in my home directory I have repo directory where I made repo

```
mkdir repo && cd repo
mkdir eshop.git && cd eshop.git
git init --bare
```

and create post-receive hooks for git

```
#!/bin/sh
git --work-tree=/var/www/shop --git-dir=/var/repo/eshop.git checkout -f
```

I want automatic deploy from my localhost to my live website with git. I also have git repsitory for this website in Bitbucket (origin). How I must setting the permisiion for the `/var/www/shop`